# Draggable droppable not working on table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to implement draggable - droppable on table. I've added class `dragItem` to the draggable area (first `input` in the row). Nothing happens when this area is dragged (I would like whole row to show draggable effect and when dropped, to reposition inside table).

Is it possible to implement draggable - droppable on this table?

Example is [here](http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/OWNjmj?editors=1010)

HTML code:

```
<table id="tableUSNW">
<thead>
<th id="th1">Stolpec 1</th>
  <th id="th2">Stolpec 2</th>
  <th id="th3">Stolpec 3</th>
    </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr data-userkey="test1"><td><input value="drag 1" class="dragItem" readonly></td><td id="td1" data-ref="test1"><input id="inputChk" type="checkbox"></td><td>test2</td><td id="td3">test XX</td></tr>
  <tr data-userkey="test2"><td><input value="drag 2" class="dragItem" readonly></td><td id="td1" data-ref="test2"><input id="inputChk" type="checkbox"></td><td>test3</td><td id="td3">test YY</td></tr>
  <tr data-userkey="test3"><td><input value="drag 3" class="dragItem" readonly></td><td id="td1" data-ref="test3"><input id="inputChk" type="checkbox"></td><td>test4</td><td id="td3">test ZZ</td></tr>
  <tr data-userkey="test4"><td><input value="drag 4" class="dragItem" readonly></td><td id="td1" data-ref="test4"><input id="inputChk" type="checkbox"></td><td>test5</td><td id="td3">test BB</td></tr>
  <tr data-userkey="test5"><td><input value="drag 5" class="dragItem" readonly></td><td id="td1" data-ref="test5"><input id="inputChk" type="checkbox"></td><td>test6</td><td id="td3">test CC</td></tr>


  <tbody>
</table>

<br/>
<br/>
```

JQuery:

```
$(function(){

  $(".dragItem").draggable();

      $( "#tableUSNW tr" ).droppable({ 
        drop: function(event, ui) { 
            $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
        }
    });

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WorkingFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/5f3csqdz/1/)

For this use sortabl.

```
$("tbody").sortable({
  items: "> tr",
  appendTo: "parent",
  helper: "clone"
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. May I ask you what is wrong on this example - I've used same code for sortable: http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/mRPBwj?editors=1010

Comment: It seems to work even this example but you must drag/drop outside the text area inputs. Maybe create a special icon on the tbody to have some good UI/UX.

Comment: I've found out the answer - if there are not elements in <td>, row can be dragged on this <td>. If there is <input> inside, it doesn't work.